# Insert a large data from csv file into database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm using *csvreader.php* to process the work. so the problem is when i try to upload file with 30k row in localhost , the script work fine, but when i use it ipage host it gives me ***Internal Server Error*** after 30 second.
this is the code i'm using:

```
$result = $this->csvreader->parse_file('/downloads/test.csv);//path to csv file
$this->admin_model->add_csv($result);
```

and this is the model i'm using:

```
public function add_csv($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert_batch('my_contacts', $data); 
    }
```

As i said before the script work fine on localhost (more than 30k row ) and also on ipage but just if there are less than 1k row . 
so how can i make this script work on ipage just like localhost

Answer (score 1):

If the CSV data is safe and you're sure there's no security risk, Try using the MySQL command: `LOAD DATA INLINE`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

It's *blazing* fast for importing large CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

If it's dying at 30 seconds, it's almost certainly a server timeout.  Check your php.ini and server configuration settings.

In the past, I've had to batch very large DB insert jobs where there's a high overhead from import, conversion, and writing.

Answer (score 0):

The file may be taking too long to execute due to the large size of your CSV.

Try increasing the setting of the max execution time of your page, for example add the following to the top of your page

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Note, 300 refers to 300 seconds or 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

i did make it work, i modify php.ini , i made:

```
Max_input_time  = -1 // unlimited
Max_execution_time = -1 // unlimited
Memory_limit = 258M
```

i tried with max_execution_time = 1000 but it didn't work it work just after i make those unlimited .
thanks anyway all of you .

Comment: 0 = unlimited, not -1 and all php settings should be lowercase

Comment: Using unlimited execution time in a web-based PHP script (ran by apache) is a VERY VERY bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable solution for such issues, is to make it step-wise. i.e don't try to add all records in one execution.

Your CSV file has many lines, each line should be a row in the database. Make it like pagination, in each page, let we say, it will insert 15 rows.

In other words, begin it as reading from the CSV file and paginate its contents, then insert those contents, then using any redirect technique (I prefer [client-side](/questions/tagged/client-side), i.e using javascript) redirect to the next page.